# How to solve application with power spike one time per 24 hour

Tags: current-limiting, ups, ac-motor

We have a building where many similar systems run heaters and valves off a 400VAC, 3 phase, 63 ampere supply (45 kW maximum.)

Internal control software in each system turn the heaters and valves on almost at random to control temperature and atmosphere in each system. The heaters and valves are typically on for 10 - 30 seconds and then they turn off again, thus the power usage fluctuates.

On average the entire system uses less than 45 kW, thus it generally run without problems. Every now and again most of the heaters turn on at the same moment and then we draw too much current and the fuses blow. The fuses blow almost one time per 24 hours. There are more than 50 individual heaters.

We see 4 solutions:

1. Change the control software such that the individual systems coordinate when they turn on heaters to avoid all at the same time. (This is expensive and difficult.)
2. Supply more power to the building. (This is expensive and will cause a delay).
3. Change the electrical supply system by inserting a current limiter which will lower the voltage to never exceed 63 ampere supply per phase. I don't know if such a component exist.
4. Insert a 3 phase, 50 Hz, 400VAC energy storage system which can supply more than 45 kW for e.g. 10 seconds during these rare power spikes. (Battery + 3 phase, 63A UPS.)

We imagine that millions of people have had similar problems when starting large AC motors under load.

Does anyone here have experience with similar problems and off the shelf products which can potentially solve point 3 or 4?

Comment: Option 1 sounds ideal.

Comment: Do you have the source code for the software? If the heaters run at low duty cycle, perhaps use less powerful heaters?

Comment: Seems a typical load shedding problem to me and typically is solved *coordinating* the loads so that only so many can run at the same time. I.E. your solution 1. AFAIK everyone does that

Comment: What options do you have to temporarily suspend one system? Can you disconnect the heater with a big relay?

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback. We spend several days researching each of the options. We ended up going with installing a new cable with more power to the building. It was the lowest cost of the choices we had.

Answer (score 1):

Yours is a very common practical problem. There needs to be coordination between the systems.

There are many ways to achieve such coordination – perhaps the systems are connected to a common ethernet network and can exchange data that way. Perhaps you can run 4-20mA current loops between the systems to communicate remaining power that way.

No matter what the communication means are, though, the overarching idea is the same:

1. Form a ring of systems.
2. One system in the chain is designated as a token holder.
3. Each system that doesn’t hold the token:

   - receives a power budget from the predecessor,
   - subtracts its own power use, based on heater state,
   - transmits remaining power budget to the successor.
4. The token holder ignores the input from its predecessor, and uses the “max available power” value as its input instead.
5. Should a system receive zero or negative power budget, it inhibits the heater. It sheds its load.

Since, in your application, the need for load shedding is infrequent, the token holder designation is static. One system always has the token.

If the need for load shedding was much more frequent, there would be concern that the systems at the end of the chain would underperform in their tasks, since they’d be the ones to shed load most often. In that case, the systems would periodically pass the token to the next system in the chain.

The token-passing can be also controlled in other ways, but the periodic rotation is adequate.

Passing the token can be easily implemented even with simple one-way analog signal passing between systems in the ring.

1. On power-up, a fixed system assumes the token. Others assume they don’t have token.
2. A token holder has a fixed duration timer that starts when the token is acquired.
3. When the timer expires, the available power gets reset to 0.
4. The token-holder waits for the 0 to propagate around the ring to the input.
5. The analog output is driven to a special state, outside its normal operating range.

   Say a 0-5V output would be normally between 1V indicating “no power left” to 5V indicating “full power left”. When the token is to be passed, the output goes down to 0V.
6. Any system in the ring that receives this special “pass the token” indicator on its input immediately assumes the token and proceeds as normal.
7. The system that was waiting to pass its token along waits until its input becomes non-zero, then goes into normal operating mode.

There are simple improvements on the above analog scheme. For example, the signal can be PWM instead of voltage, or even can be serial data passed unidirectionally. The token passing can be implemented without disrupting the operation by adding a “flag” to the signal, eg. making the voltage or PWM bipolar, and the load shedding uses the absolute value of the input signal, whereas the sign is used for the token passing actions only.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't my field, so I'm adding options based on logic and things that could be done in smaller systems.

- Taking turns: pair up neighbouring  heaters such that the signal that turns one on disables its partner.  This is a dumb way of coordinating loads, made slightly smarter if designed by an engineer who understands the process.  Assuming your loads are switched by contactors (if large, relays if many small heaters), you might use relays in the control lines.
- Thermal, i.e. consider your heat losses: could insulation, or even reduced flow through the valves reduce your duty cycle. Similarly increasing thermal mass will slow both heating and cooling, but decreasing thermal mass will speed it up, potentially meaning less overcurrent time.  Do you want rapid heating or constant temperature?
- Changing heaters - while the average power demand is the same, lower power heaters that run for longer will reduce the peak demand.  Again, this depends on whether you want to maintain a temperature or briefly heat something.  You'd need to lower the peak current quite a bit, as the peak will last longer

Possibly in addition

- If certain loads are more sensitive than others, provide local backup power for those (especially if these are valves which I assume to have lower average power consumption) to ride-out the downtime, whether caused by fuses blowing or my first suggestion.
- Alternatively breakers on less-critical sections would trip those out (probably more frequently) allowing more-critical parts to keep running

But note that you'll need to specify the temperature swings you can tolerate at each heater - with any method.  Most of your options will increase your deadband.  That may be your biggest consideration in choosing a solution.  Fixing the software would allow a degree of prioritisation.

If you're getting downtime as a result of this almost daily, almost anything will be an improvement - and note that if fuses are blowing in 10-30s you've got significant overcurrent.

Note that your option 3, if it existed, would induce brownouts.  Can all your kit tolerate them?